# Why does Passenger says that my gem 'json' can't be found, when my gem list shows it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, passenger, gemset

I got the following error message with phusion passenger for Ruby on Rails on my Apache server :

```
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. This is probably because your
application is being run under a different environment than it's supposed to.
Please check the following:

 * Is this app supposed to be run as the `rvm_admin` user?
 * Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
   see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
 * Are you using RVM? Please check whether the correct gemset is being used.
 * If all of the above fails, try resetting your RVM gemsets:
   https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets

-------- The exception is as follows: -------
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

It is weird because when I perform a gem list command :

```
rvm_admin@myserver:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.16)
actionpack (3.2.16)
activemodel (3.2.16)
activerecord (3.2.16)
activeresource (3.2.16)
activesupport (3.2.16)
annotate (2.6.1)
arel (3.0.3)
atomic (1.1.14)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.3)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.5.2)
capistrano (3.0.1)
chunky_png (1.2.9)
coffee-rails (3.2.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
compass (0.12.2)
compass-rails (1.1.3)
declarative_authorization (0.5.7)
devise (3.2.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.2)
faker (1.2.0)
fssm (0.2.10)
haml (4.0.5)
haml-rails (0.4)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.0)
json (1.8.1)
libv8 (3.16.14.3 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
net-scp (1.1.2)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
pg (0.17.1)
polyamorous (0.6.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.2)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.16)
rails-translate-routes (0.1.3)
railties (3.2.16)
rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0, 3.12.2)
ref (1.0.5)
role_model (0.8.1)
rspec-core (2.14.7)
rspec-expectations (2.14.4)
rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
rspec-rails (2.14.1)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
sass (3.2.14)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
schema_plus (1.3.2)
spreadsheet (0.9.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
squeel (1.1.1)
sshkit (1.0.0)
term-ansicolor (1.2.2)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
therubyracer (0.12.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
timeliness (0.3.7)
tins (0.13.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)
uglifier (2.4.0)
validates_timeliness (3.0.14)
valuable (0.9.8)
warden (1.2.3)
```

json appear to be there

But the If I do a

```
rvm_admin@myserver:~$ bundle show json
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Why is that ?

For info here are my **gemsets** :

```
rvm_admin@myserver:~$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.0 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0)
=> (default)
   global
```

So no other gemsets except the global one.

This is my **Gemfile** :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.14'
gem 'haml-rails' , '>= 0.3'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :developpement do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.11'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0.1'
  gem 'faker', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'sshkit', '~> 1.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '>= 2.11'
  gem 'webrat', '>= 0.7'
  gem 'spork-rails', '>= 3.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '>= 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'spreadsheet' #, '~> 0.7'
gem 'schema_plus' #, :git => "git://github.com/lomba/schema_plus.git"
gem 'squeel' #, '~> 1.0'
gem 'devise' #, '~> 2.1'
gem 'role_model'
gem 'declarative_authorization'
gem 'rails-translate-routes'  #, '~> 0.1'
gem 'validates_timeliness'  #, '~> 3.0'
```

I install manually the gems with `bundle install --without developement test` command.
I don't want that Capistrano perform any sort of server package installation. So I unistalled gems such as *capistrano-rvm* or *capisttrano-rails*.

What's wrong ? What should I do ?

=== Edit

If I go into my app folder and check fo Json it appear to be present :

```
rvm_admin@myserver:/var/www/odpf/current$ bundle show json
The gem json has been deleted. It was installed at:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.1
```

Comment: Have you tried including `gem 'json'` in the Gemfile? (Run `bundle install` again after modifying the Gemfile)

Comment: yes I did this with bundle install `--without development` test and the issue remains the same. Moreover if I try to uninstall json gem from my app folder it says that : gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this.
The issue was coming from **Phusion passenger ruby interpreter string**.

As Phusion passenger is no more a gem, but a package now, apt-get will install a depency package : an old versioned ruby package

So even I installed a single version of ruby with RVM (ruby 2.1.0), Phusion Passenger was using the one (1.9.3) delivered in the package at /usr/bin/ruby, and therefore Passenger was somehow looking for gems into this interpreter folder. Of course he couldn't find the required gems because they were installed in relationship with ruby 2.1.0 and not with ruby 1.9.3.

Performing a `rvm gemset list` command will show you which gemset is currently used but unfortunately we can not make the asumption that when we install gems they goes inside the current gemset.
It is more complex and obscure than that. It seems the folder location where you install your gems does matter.
Moreover the gems displayed by the `gem list` command is almost useless to troubleshoot gems issues. Installing ruby environnement on a server is really a pain....

The [bundler web site](http://bundler.io/v1.5/deploying.html) deployement page explains this a 'little' bit. I never found a good and detailed explanation on how gems are managed by rvm and bundler.

To solve the issue, I had to perform the following command

```
passenger-config --ruby-command
```

The output gave me the "ruby interpreter command" to copy and paste into my 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite apache config file :

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby
```

However I instead placed it in the global section of my config file within the PassengerDefaultRuby parameter to make sure that any ruby helper tools use this version and only this version of ruby 2.1.0 :

```
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby
```

**More information about how to setup the ruby interpreter string** are explained [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) in the "RVM helper tool" section.

I highly recommand to read it.

Comment: Thanks this was a big help -- I ran into a similar problem when installing passenger in the rvm global gemset but had my rails app running from it's own gemset.   Passenger seemed to resultantly search for everything in global

Answer (score 0):

I was using ubuntu 14.04 and nginx and get the error:

> Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

so, I run the command:

```
$ passenger-config --ruby-command
```

and I change the variable: `passenger_ruby` in the file `nginx.conf` to the value of "To use in Nginx". It worked perfectly.